# Start system activity inside my own layout

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity

my app uses TabHost layout. Each tab has one Activity. One of my tabs has to only start  systems Music Player activity so I used `startActivity(new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER));` . But then I loose sight of my tabs. Is there a possibility to open Music player inside my layout ?

Answer (score 0):

in a tab layout, you can only include activities that are declared in your application's manifest file.